# How to close (make unavailable) a Sharepoint Survey after a certain amount of responses.

Tags: survey-list

We are using the SharePoint Survey functionality as a place to RSVP for an event. What I am trying to accomplish is any anytime someone tries to go to the RSVP page (the sp survey) after the event capacity is reached, it automatically displays a page that indicates the event is full.  I don’t know if this is even possible with SharePoint and/or if a custom workflow would accommodate this request, but wanted to through this out there for some ideas.

I am be no means a SP whiz and I would like to avoid digging into the code as we do not have a SP DEV environment.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you use SP Designer?